# Divide n Words into a random 16 word partition

Tags: javascript, math

i'm writing a cleromancy SPA. I have a book of n words. I roll a quantum die giving me a number 1-16. I now want the book divided into partitions 1-16 (each containing n / 16 words). I keep dividing this partition (containing n/16 words) by 16, and so on, until i have found a section of the book containing 1-16 words.

I want a random 1-16 word partition of a String using n rolls of a die 1-16.

Can anyone give me the javascript or discrete math to do this? (I can't use a javascript String fn because i'm using a Quantum Random Number Generator to generate true randomness).

I'm not very good at math I'm more of a magician so I hope you understand my question!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+random+words+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Also post how you get the numbers. For example https://qrng.anu.edu.au/API/jsonI.php?length=1&type=uint8&size=1 does not do 1-16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the book contents.  The whole thing that you need to calculate ahead of time is the number of words in a book.  Let's just assume we have an variable called `numWords` that are the number of words in your book.

Once we know the word count, let's have a little helper function to split a range of word indices into 16 contiguous sections and returns a random section from that split.

```
// your implementation returns a value between [0-15]
function rollDie16() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*16);  // replace with your own Random Number generator
}

function pickRandomSection(first, last) {

    let len = last-first+1;
    if (len <= 16) {
        return {first, last};
    }

    let sliceSize = Math.floor(len/16);  // divide index range into 16 "slices"
    let residual = len % 16;  // any left over words go into the last slice

    // pick a random slice
    let sliceIndex = rollDie16();

    first = sliceIndex * sliceSize + first;
    last = first + sliceSize - 1;
    if (sliceIndex == 15) {
        last += residual;
    }

    return {first, last};
}
```

And then you just need to invoke the above function until you get a section that is 16 words or less.  Each iteration of the while loop is consider a "dice roll".

```
let section = {first:0, last:numWords};
let section_length = section.last - section.first + 1;
while (section_length) > 16) {
    section = pickRandomSection(section.first, section.last);
    section_length = section.last - section.first + 1;
}
```

`section` now contains the word indices between `first` and `last`.

Putting it altogether:

```
let book = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non nunc a libero aliquam aliquam. Nulla eu orci orci. Praesent finibus magna odio, gravida porttitor risus bibendum id. Etiam non dui mollis, consectetur nisl id, gravida enim. Sed ut ullamcorper lectus. Integer venenatis augue eu felis efficitur consectetur. In vestibulum ex nec sapien semper vehicula."

let words = book.split(' ').filter(word=>word.length>0);
let numWords = words.length;

let section = {first:0, last:numWords};
let section_length = section.last - section.first + 1;
while (section_length) > 16) {
    section = pickRandomSection(section.first, section.last);
    section_length = section.last - section.first + 1;
}

for (let j = section.first; j <= section.last; j++) {
   console.log(words[j+section.first]);
}
```